# IBM Watson Dialog Concept

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-dialog

I am creating Watson Dialog Service. My question is : do we always need the formatted XML file for the input or is there a way by which we can feed data in to Watson from other sources like from several web URLs etc? Because when we will have a huge amount of data how XML will be able to deal and creating of XML files will also be difficult as data grows. Kindly help to understand the basic concept.

Comment: Is your question specifically about the Watson dialog script or the corpus used by other Watson components such as Retrieve and Rank?

Comment: My question is what should be my approach if I want to avoid XML file but want to feed Watson with huge data and utilize in Dialog Service. Please help me to explain the architecture that I should follow (may include other Watson Services also).

Comment: You cannot avoid XML files if you want to use the dialog service in its present form.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure an existing XML Dialog by setting up profile variables.

The *Set Profile Variables* API call on the Dialog Service is key to priming up a dialog: https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/dialog-v1#/

Sadly, this is also the most poorly documented call in their docs.

Have a look at the *What's in Theaters* example from IBM. This is by far the most comprehensive application that shows how their Dialog Service can interact with other Watson enabled services like Natural Language Classifier and also third party apps.

- Source Code: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/movieapp-dialog
- Documnentation: http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/ega_docs/dialog_ega.shtml

Based on this you have to decide if the Dialog service is suitable for your purpose or can play a small role in your larger application when combined with other services.

Conversational Agent Application Starter Kit: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversational-agent-application-starter-kit

Comment: The What's in the theaters is considered deprecated now (I don't know why) and it links to the Conversational Agent.

Comment: The new conversation service (currently in beta)  will replace Dialog. It's better and has a web up for designing the Dialog flow.